# Nested traits not seen as diffrent

Tags: scala, traits, path-dependent-type

So I have some code like this

```
 trait DependentTrait {
   trait res
 }

 case class DepWith[A <: DependentTrait, B <: DependentTrait](val a : A, val b : B) extends DependentTrait {
   //trait resn extends a.res with b.res {}
   trait res extends a.res with b.res
 }
```

But I get an error saying that 'res' inherits from 'res' twice. It was my understanding that the trait 'res' mentioned in DependentTrait could refer to any implementing class's trait named 'res' and thus 'a.res' and 'b.res' not not strictly different. I must have misunderstood something here. What have I misunderstood? Is there a way to do what I am trying to do (create a type which composes two types)?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible.. As it stands, you aren't proving that `A` and `B` are actually different types, and I'm not sure how you can.

Comment: Why should I have to prove that they are different?

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know they *aren't* the same type (they both have the same upper-bound, so they very well could be the same type), or that implementations of `res` may be different, so it sees it as an error.

Comment: Ah that make sense. I suppose scala doesn't let me make use of proof objects in anyway does it. Is there some way to push the check off to the time of instantiation the way C++ does?

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. I don't suppose some kind of proof object could help me could it?